# Запись в файл значений класса?

Tags: c++, c, массивы, классы, arraylist

```
class Animal{
    private:
        char vid[80];
        char *osobennost;
        int srokjizni;
    public:
        Animal();
        Animal(char *v, char *os, int s);
        Animal(Animal &a);
        Animal(char *);
        void setvid(char *v);
        void setosobennost(char *s);
        void setsrokjizni(int j);
        char *getvid();
        char *getosobennost();
        int getsrokjizni();
        int find(int n, char *d);
        void scan();
        void print();
        virtual ~Animal();    
};
```

этот код

```
FILE *pt;
Animal *a;
a = find(0);
fprintf(pt, "%s %s %d", a);
```

Но в результате почему то в файл записывается два одинаковых первых слова "Cat Cat 1", а должен быть записана особенность "Cat Black 1" - то есть, не получается взять osobennost, 3-ю переменную в классе.

Comment: `fprintf` ожидает три аргумента после строки формата, а получает один (ещё й указатель на Ваш тип). Может так:`fprintf(pt, "%s %s %d", a->getvid(), a->getosobennost(), a->getsrokjizni());`?

Comment: Спасибо, помогло !